# Android 4.4 WebView CSS/JS issues

Tags: android, webview

Starting with Android version 4.4 the html files in WebView are no longer loading CSS when linked from a css file.

There are lot of discussions and threads on this issue. None of the suggested workarounds did the trick for me.

Based on suggested workarounds I removed  from the html files. If I do this the CSS works on tablets but not on Phones(Tested on Samsung phones s3 and s5).

The other workaround suggested in Titanium is to set borderRadius greater than 1. Based on this I am setting border-radius:1 for my body tag in HTML but no luck.

Just checking if any one got this issue solved. Thanks

---EDIT---

If I copy the external CSS to interanl CSS (style in HEAD) of the html files it is recognizing the css. But this is just a workaround. Trying to see if I can find something better.

---EDIT 2 ---

Was able to resolve by using File based URIs 'file://' instead of 'content://' based URIs in webview.

Comment: Totally untested idea: move your linked CSS file up/down a directory level in `assets/`. I have experienced problems sometimes (not regarding CSS though) if a file is in the root `assets/` folder, and other times if the file **isn't** there.

Comment: Actually I am using Content Provider to load the files.HTML, CSS and JS are all on the same directory on SD card. Looks like something changed from 4.4 the way files are loaded. Will post if I get any solution.